# How to add dialog in webview using this code

Tags: java, android, webview

I have this `webview` code working fine but I want to add a loading dialog to it. I tried several times but when I put the `dialog` code in my code the `webview` crashes all the time. Please help me.

```
import java.net.URL;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
ProgressDialog mProgress;

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
          ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(banks.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl(message);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    String url = message;

    myWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String     mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


}

}
```

Comment: which code you mean?

Comment: ohh sorry I think its deleted

Comment: Are you trying to show a loader dialog?

Comment: yes I want to show you my code but how to upload it

Comment: mark the regarding code. hit ctrl + c. go to this place and hit ctrl + v.

Comment: I think the reason your app crashes is, that there is no app on your phone which can show the kind of data you're downloading. What data format are you downloading?

Comment: Its downloading data perfectly by using down-loader but I want to add a dialog to it when my page is loading in webview "Loading...Page Please Wait"

Comment: Like a progress bar when page loading finished the dialog should be invisible

Comment: Okay simple do this, implement the onPageStarted and onPageFinished methods in the Webview client. Start your dialog in the onPageStarted and onPageFinished cancel the dialog. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html

Comment: OK thank you very much let me try if something happen I'll inform you :)

Comment: It really worked thanx but one problem when it shows loading message I cant go back by using back button

Comment: it stays loading until I close app

Comment: You should set the cancelable property of your dialog as true. If my comment helped you, i will put it as an answer so accept it please.